# c# wpf multiple line drawing on canvas with kinect sensor

Tags: c#, wpf, draw, kinect, lines

So first of all let me show you what I want to accomplish:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=endscreen&v=FdwZEepJxJ4

There the guy is drawing a long curved line using kinect. I need to make something similar. I had several ideas with just simple code like

layoutGrid.Children.Add(myLine)

This works, but not the way I want.

I was thinking I could use drawingContext to draw lines with:

drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, pointprev, point1);

The problem is that by using this drawing method the lines I draw are not kept on the screen. It's like the line is always redrawn. How do I keep my lines?

By the way I also don't understand why the skeleton drawn by the same method gets updated and we don't need to clear the previous lines in the image?

```
private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create the drawing group we'll use for drawing
            this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

            // Create an image source that we can use in our image control
            this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);

            // Display the drawing using our image control
            Image2.Source = this.imageSource;

            ************Some other code here*******
         }


 private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            *****************Some code to get skeleton data here********

            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {

                if (skeletons.Length != 0)
                {
                    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                    {

                        if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                        {

                            this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);                            
                        }

                    }
                }
            }           
        }


private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            ***********************Some code to draw skeleton***************

            Joint righthand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];

            if (init == true)
            {
                pointprev = SkeletonPointToScreen(righthand.Position);
                init = false;
                return;
            }


            Point point1 = SkeletonPointToScreen(righthand.Position);

            Pen drawPen = this.trackedBonePen;

            drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, pointprev, point1);


            pointprev = point1;

        }

private Point SkeletonPointToScreen(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
        {
            // Convert point to depth space.  
            // We are not using depth directly, but we do want the points in our 640x480 output resolution.
            DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skelpoint, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
            return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
        }


        private void DrawBone(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext, JointType jointType0, JointType jointType1)
        {
            Joint joint0 = skeleton.Joints[jointType0];
            Joint joint1 = skeleton.Joints[jointType1];          

            Pen drawPen = this.trackedBonePen;   

            drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint0.Position),       this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint1.Position));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I keep my lines?

You would have to either use a [Polyline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline.aspx) or draw a [PathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx) or a [StreamGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx) into a DrawingContext by [DrawGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawgeometry.aspx). The geometry would have to contain one or more polyline segments.